# Simple XPath expression doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, xpath, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to parse a web document (table-design based), and I have a div with a table inside.

```
<div id="component">
   <table ...>
      ....
```

If I try with:

```
XmlXPathSelector(response).select("//*[@id='component']")
```

This works:

```
[<XmlXPathSelector xpath="//*[@id='component']" data=u'<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>]
```

But if I want to list the contained tables:

```
XmlXPathSelector(response).select("//*[@id='component']/table")
```

This returns an empty result. I tried with other selectors such as `"//*[@id='component']/tr"` and `"//*[@id='component']/a"` but those don't work either.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Please post the `html document`.

Comment: From your sample it should be `"news"`, not `"component"`.

Comment: Yes I know, I was write this HTML as sample, it isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

:P I solved this, I was using XmlPathSelector instead of **HTML**PathSelector